# Using Realm, how can I store a query's Results in a global property and access it?

Tags: swift, realm

I'm currently working on a Swift app and I'm using Realm to persist my data locally. My first view controller is a table view controller and I populate it using a specific object stored in my Realm Database, but Realm's documentation says that once you get a **Results** from a query, that Results is self-updated every once in a while or through a notification-block.

I want to know how to declare or store that **Results** globally in my Table View Controller to be able to access it and populate my table every time I add an object of this kind into my database.

This is to avoid querying the database manually every time I want to reload the data in my table.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Best way of achieving what you want is to use Realm notification blocks:

```
let token = realm.objects(YourObject).addNotificationBlock { results, error in
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Code above will reload your TableView's data any time a change happens to any of `YourObject`s

Comment: But should I place that inside the viewDidLoad? Because I need to globally reference that self-updating collection to specify the number of rows with `.count` property and if I use that globally but within my class I get the following message `Instance member 'realm' cannot be user on type 'MyClass'`. @bcamur

Comment: Create a class variable and in the notification block assign the count of `results` to that variable.